# GoogleMap class not found

Tags: android, google-maps, gradle

I am adding play services in gradle, but I It does not give me **GoogleMap** class.

I am getting compiler error in import:

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.*;
```

This my gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
}
```

Any idea what am I missing?

*Been trying to rebuild the project, reimport gradle and do clean.*

Comment: That should be OK. However, for a smaller APK, you might try switching to `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.0.0'`, to pull in only MapsV2. Beyond that, are you sure that you are modifying the right `build.gradle` file for the source that you are working with?

Comment: yeah, and I been trying that the smaller solution too. I just don't know what went wrong

Comment: You could compare and contrast your projects with some of mine, like [this one](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/MapsV2/NooYawk). It happens to pull in `6.5.87` rather than `7.0.0`, but that should not matter with respect to your issue.

Comment: @CommonsWare I think that some how the indexing failed on this module. And I don't know how to redo it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried and just do the step from [here](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#Setup) and it works.

[image]

[image]

If not work, you can try to create a new project.

Also you can try `File`---> `Invalidate Caches and Restart`

Answer (score 0):

Just follow these steps

1.[Download this google-play-services jar file](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/google-play/google-play-services.jar.zip)

2.copy in to **Your Project -> libs -> Copy that jar file here **

3.Clean the particular project

4.And, You can import all the classes you required such as GoogleMaps , MapFragment .

Let me know in the comments if you are still facing problem.